# What are the nuclear energy challenges specific to the moon?

Tags: the-moon, engines, colonization, nuclear, energy

What are moon specific hurdles to a fission reactor?

- low gravity
- no atmosphere

Apparently it's more difficult to shed heat in a vacuum.  Are some coolants more advantageous on the moon than others?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_affordable_fission_engine

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilopower

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SP-100

I ask because there's been a fair amount of discussion of moving away from using water, at least for civilian reactors.

Comment: For large amounts of power we should ask @KimHolder. For hundreds of kW or less an array of modest kilopower type reactors appear to have this all thought out.